# Why there is no unwrapping performed when the ref is used as an element inside reactive array or reactive Map?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

The [vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-templates) reads as follows:

> Unlike reactive objects, there is no unwrapping performed when the `ref` is accessed as an element of a `reactive array` or a native collection type like `Map`

And the sample given as follows:

```
const books = reactive([ref('Vue 3 Guide')])
// need .value here
console.log(books[0].value)

const map = reactive(new Map([['count', ref(0)]]))
// need .value here
console.log(map.get('count').value)
```

But, ref is automatically unwrapped when used inside `reactive` **object** as below:

> When a ref is accessed or mutated as a property of a reactive object, it is also automatically unwrapped so it behaves like a normal property

And the sample code was as follows in the documentation:

```
const count = ref(0)
const state = reactive({
  count
})

console.log(state.count) // 0

state.count = 1
console.log(count.value) // 1
```

Can anyone explain why this behaviour ? Why can't we access values of `ref` element inside `reactive` **array** without using `.value`?

Answer (score 1):

Why ? Design decision of the Vue team.

If you want to know more details about the reasons behind such decision (at least for arrays) try this issue: [Stable mutation of reactive arrays containing refs](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/737)

> I'm starting to think that Arrays should not automatically unwrap refs it contains. With ref unwrapping it becomes very complicated to ensure expected behavior for all the built-in Array methods. (Evan You)